# media type is unsupported error while passing values to payment gateway

Tags: php, opencart, payment-gateway

im building a payment extension for my opencart website. im trying to populate all the data and send it to the payment gateway for verification. But when i click on pay i get the below error from the payment page.

> The server cannot service the request because the media type is
>   unsupported.

below is the template file of my checkout form. I did a dump bf the values. all the values are populated properly. But the error comes when i try to pass to the gateway.

```
<form action="http://xxxxxx/verify/verification.svc?wsdlp" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="HyperId" value="<?php echo $HyperId; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="HyperName" value="<?php echo $HyperName; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="HyperPhone" value="<?php echo $HyperPhone; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="HyperEmail" value="<?php echo $HyperEmail; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="HyperAmount" value="<?php echo $HyperAmount; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="Hyperinvoice" value="<?php echo $Hyperinvoice; ?>" />
   <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?php echo $callback; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="fail_url" value="<?php echo $callback; ?>" />
     <input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="<?php echo $cancel; ?>" />
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="right">
      <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_confirm; ?>" class="button" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

can someone please tell me what am i doing wrong here

Comment: Did You try adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute into the `<form>` tag? It might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, taking in regard the specific error you get, i would suggest you check your supported mime types in your server, if you have cpanel you may have a "MIME Types" section,

and you can try and add it there: Extension: .svc, MIME type: application/octet-stream

or with .htaccess `AddType application/octet-stream .svc`

I am not saying that this is the solution to your problem but it may be something worth checking for.

Hope i helped.